# Laravel downloads a file with unknown type

Tags: laravel, download

I am using Laravel 4. I allow users to upload a file, which is programmatically renamed with some number and stored. I also allow them to download the files, though I am supposed to rename their file from some funny number to their name, and download it.

My problem is, how can I change filename just before its downloaded?

My code:

```
return Response::download($pathToFile, $name);
```

When I do that, the file is downloaded with unknown format.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't send a `Content-Type` header with the response? Also, does this happen for any file you try?

Comment: I tried for .doc and .pdf, it downloads with unknown format .. . if i just try this return Response::download($pathToFile);  i.e without renaming it works perfectly fine

Comment: Does the `$name` parameter include the extension of the file?

Comment: no it does not. Does it supposed to include extension?

Comment: Yes it does. I've posted a solution as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second `$name` parameter, needs to include the full filename (including the file extension). The `download` method does not automatically detect the extension from the file path and append it to the name, so that needs to be done manually. Something like this will work:

```php
return Response::download(
    $pathToFile,
    $name . '.' . pathinfo($pathToFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)
);
```

Comment: Thanks! you are a definately a life saver!